# Facelet not being rendered

Tags: spring, jsf, richfaces

I am trying to migrate our project from RicFaces3 to Richfaces4.With the help of similar post available here, I was able to resolve all the build issues.However my login page doesn't load, when I try access the application `http://localhost:8080/expense-portal/` , it shows a File Download window instead. I am copying all the config and xhtml here.Would really appreciate if someone can help.

#### web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<display-name>expense-portal</display-name>
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml /WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>



<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.mpro.expense.portal.ui.listener.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
<param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!--<context-param> <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name> 
<param-value>NONE</param-value> </context-param> -->



<!-- Faces Servlet -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Faces Servlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>authenticationFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>

<init-param>
<param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
<param-value>authenticationFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>authenticationFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- error servlet -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Error Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.mpro.expense.portal.ui.error.ErrorHandlingServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>applicationName</param-name>
<param-value>Expense Portal</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>errorPage</param-name>
<param-value>/error.jsf</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Error Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/error</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
<exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
<location>/error</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
<location>/sessionExpired.jsf</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<error-code>401</error-code>
<location>/login.jsf</location>
</error-page>

<session-config>
<session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

#### faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <application>
        <variable-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.DelegatingVariableResolver</variable-resolver>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
        <!-- <view-handler>org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler</view-handler> -->
    </application>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>login.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect />
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <converter>
        <converter-for-class>java.lang.String</converter-for-class>
        <converter-class>com.mpro.expense.portal.ui.util.EmptyToNullConverter</converter-class>
    </converter>
</faces-config>
```

#### login.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<head>
<title>Expense Portal</title>

<link href="css/stylemask.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict()
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //         
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    if (filename.indexOf("login.jsf") == -1) {
        window.location = "/expense-portal/login.jsf"
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    });
    //
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="width: 480px; position:absolute; top:50%;left:50%;margin-left:-240px; margin-top:-190px;">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
            <b>Expense Portal</b>
            <span><h:outputText value="#{homepageBean.environment}" /></span>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

        <h:form id="form">
            <h:messages id="resultMsg" errorClass="error-message" infoClass="info-message" />

            <div class="input-row">
                <div class="required">*</div>
                <h:outputLabel id="usernameLabel" for="username" value="Username:" />
                <h:inputText id="username" styleClass="text" maxlength="255" value="#{loginBean.username}">
                    <rich:beanValidator />
                </h:inputText>
            </div>
            <div class="input-row">
                <div class="required">*</div>
                <h:outputLabel id="passwordLabel" for="password" value="Password: " />
                <h:inputSecret id="password" styleClass="text" maxlength="50" value="#{loginBean.password}">
                    <rich:beanValidator />
                </h:inputSecret>
            </div>
            <div class="input-row">
                <div class="required">*</div>
                <h:outputLabel id="domainLabel" for="domain" value="Domain: " />
                <h:selectOneMenu styleClass="text" id="domain" value="#{loginBean.domain}">
                    <rich:beanValidator />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{userManagementBean.domainList}"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>


            <h:commandButton id="loginBtn" value="Login" class="submit-button" action="#{loginBean.login}" />
        </h:form>

        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does http://localhost:8080/expense-portal/login.jsf render the page?

Comment: Hi mabi, no it doesn't, get the same window "Do you want to save this file, or find a programe online to open it?"

Comment: Unfortunate. It seems like your FacesServlet isn't registered properly or Spring interferes with it. When you download the file, is it properly rendered HTML or your facelet file?

Comment: Hi mabi, Its not rendered as HTML, when I open it in Notepad I see the JSF tags in it.Don't know whats going on.